# Is "kindly" correctly used in "I kindly request to apply in your company"

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality-in-context

> I kindly request to apply in your company.

Is the usage of "kindly" correct here? I am writing a message to a company I am applying for.

Comment: *request* is a transitive verb requiring an object here. Whom are you requesting?

Comment: In my perspective, "kindly" is often used when you ask someone to (give something to you / do something for you) while you want to be polite about it. For example, you sent a registration form to the company and then the company needs you to send other document as well. They might say "Please kindly send us your [other document]."

Comment: To this US English speaker, no, it is not correct.  We use *kindly* when talking about doing a favor for someone, or talking about doing something kind.  You are not doing the company a favor by requesting something, so "kindly" is inappropriate.

Comment: Try using "humbly" instead of "kindly."  Also, you could be more specific by saying "I would like to apply for employment within your company."

Comment: @user8577930 As an American, your phrase seems verbose. What else would one apply for in a company? I'd go with "I would like to apply for the position of $position at $company_name."

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

'Kindly' means in a kind manner. That would imply that your are being 'kind' to them with your request - that you are doing them a favour by applying. As user8577930 says, 'humbly' is a much better word.

You might also consider that "request to apply" marks you out as a non-native English speaker. "Request to apply" means that you are asking them if you can apply. Assuming that you are sending a resume, then you are in fact applying, and there is no need to ask for permission. Also you apply 'to' a company not 'in' it.